# Angularjs Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider when injecting factory in controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently working on a webapp project, and I needed to add a new factory. But when I want to inject the factory in a controller (in the same module) I get the error in the title.
Here's my code :

The Commande factory (commande.service.js)

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('Commande', Commande)

Commande.$inject = ['$resource', 'DateUtils'];

function Commande ($resource, DateUtils) {
    var resourceUrl1 = 'url1';
    var resourceUrl2 = 'url2';

    return {
        byNumero : $resource(resourceUrl1, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    if(data){
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }),
        byNomMarcheAndNumero : $resource(resourceUrl2, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    if(data){
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }
        })
    }
};})()
```

The PanelCommande controller (panelCommande.controller.js)

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('PanelCommandeController', PanelCommandeController);
PanelCommandeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Commande', '$rootScope', 'Prestation'];
function PanelCommandeController($scope, Commande, $rootScope, Prestation) {
    //A lot of stuff
}})();
```

Prestation is another factory that has the same structure as Commande, and it works fine.

I have this error message :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CommandeProvider <- Commande <- PanelRepartitionProductionController <- PanelCommandeController
```

Does somebody see where is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the file `commande-service.js` included?

Comment: Indeed I found it wasn't the second you wrote the message. I look for a solution during a whole day to find it 5 minute after I've decided to ask here... Thank you anyways.

Comment: This error is in dependacy injection. any Dependency injection have provider thus it couldn't find out related provider

Comment: This error comes when u have not injected the factory/service properly.Either you have misspelled the name of the factory or you have not included the js file reference.